# Using redux thunk with debounce

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm trying to create a search ahead input bar.

I have something like this in my actions/index.js :

```
export function fetchMoviesThunk(movie) {

const doApi = _.debounce((dispatch) => { 
    axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}${API_KEY}&s=${movie}`)
      .then((data) => dispatch(fetchMoviesSuccess(data)))
    }, 300
)

return dispatch => {
   dispatch(requestFetchMovies())

   doApi(dispatch)
      //  return axios.get(`${ROOT_URL}${API_KEY}&s=${movie}`)
      //  .then((data) => dispatch(fetchMoviesSuccess(data)))

   }
 }
```

It should be delaying the search by 300ms (so that every keystroke is not captured).  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What's the issue? Does it not work? You've not been very clear in your question.

Comment: Have `doApi` equal to the arrow function. Wrap `doApi`, in your return arrow function, with debounce. Also, do you have `redux-thunk` installed and applied properly?